# Android Scaling issue

Tags: android, layout, imageview, scale, imagebutton

I'm new to Android programming and haven't found any good examples of how to make this layout work properly.....

I have all the art assets stored properly at the right DPIs for mdpi, hdpi,xhdpi, and xxhdpi.

The view has an ImageView that I want to fill the background so I set it up as follows.......

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src ="@drawable/teardrop"/>
```

And there are two ImageButtons that I want on screen, here is one of them.....

```
        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ownerSignInButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/signinbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

But the problem is the button does not scale proportionally with the screen size.  I have a 600x1024 Asus Memo pad 7 for development (hdpi image sets are used - I checked).  On that screen the ImageView fills the screen, but the button is very small on screen because the ImageButton does not appear to scale.  When I bring the image up on a Nexus S (in the simulator, which is 480x800 and also an hdpi device) the ImageView fills the screen but the ImageButtons are huge).

The ImageButtons at hdpi are 364x102.

I *think* I've tried every combination of **android:scaleType** to try and get things right but it doesn't appear to be having any effect.

Adding screenshots.....  here is the image on a 480x800 mdpi device....
[image]

And here is what it looks like on the Asus Tab.....see how the buttons are so small, why don't they scale appropriately.

[image]

Comment: Set your main layout's background like this: `android:background="@drawable/teardrop"` and remove the imageview

Comment: Did that.  Didn't see any difference.

Comment: Post the screenshot of it

Comment: Oh that. Look these are default buttons. They will always look big on small device and small on big ones. You can make a flat button background for mdpi, hdpi, xdpi and xxdpi and put them in their respective drawable folders. Then see the magic.

Comment: Those are not default buttons.  They are ImageButtons with the backgrounds being set to an @drawable/resource.......   There are four versions of each image.  They are in the corresponding mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi folder .......the images are saved at 160dpi, 240dpi, 360dpi, and 480dpi respectively.